# Is it possible to run app with different than currently selected theme?

Tags: linux-mint, theme

I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa 64bit. 
I've installed nice little app [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/)
but it doesn't cooperate well with my desktop theme. 
it looks like this:
[image]

I've tried a few dark/grey themes and Zeal seems to inherit theme properties badly no matter what, so i thought to override its styling to default Mint theme.

Is there a way to do that? Maybe some better ideas?